Complex table to make
I'm trying to reproduce this array in LaTeX but I don't have exactly the same thing.

What I tried :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|m{5cm}|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Répartition semestrielle de mathématiques 2024/2025 - Lycée Al Amana}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{2\textsuperscript{ème} année Bac. Sciences Math A et B. \quad Premier Semestre}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Semaine} & \textbf{Titres de leçons} & \textbf{Nombres d’heures} & \textbf{Devoirs Donné} & \textbf{Corrigé} \\ \hline
1 & & 8 & & \\ \hline
2 & Limites et continuité & 8 & DM1 & \\ \hline
3 & & 8 & & DM1 \\ \hline
4 & Suites numériques & 6 & DS1 & \\ \hline
5 & & 6 & & DS1 \\ \hline
6 & Dérivation et étude de fonctions & 6 & DM2 & \\ \hline
7 & & 6 & & DM2 \\ \hline
8 & Primitives & 6 & DS2 & \\ \hline
9 & & 6 & & DS2 \\ \hline
10 & Fonctions logarithmes et exponentielles & 8 & DM3 & \\ \hline
11 & & 8 & & DS3 \\ \hline
12 & & 8 & & DM3 \\ \hline
13 & Nombres Complexes & 4 & DS3 & \\ \hline
14 & & 4 & & DS4 \\ \hline
15 & Équations différentielles & 6 & DM4 & DS4 \\ \hline
16 & & 6 & & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{\textbf{Total horaire}} & \textbf{98} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{10} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

And this is the result :


Have a look at the tabularray package. It makes it easy to colour parts of the table (and reconsider the layout of the table, it does not look very professional)

To reproduce the headers in a simple tabular you can use \multirow (need the he package multirow) to combine row in and two in the columns 1 to 3 of the original table. There are tons of examples of use in this site. Just  search. See also the manual of booktabs to use partial and well placed horizontal lines,  without abuse of the lines.

What is the main problem here? Cell merging? For that, see How to merge cells vertically or Table: how to merge two cells?. Having difficulty colouring cells? For that, see color only a cell of a table

The following solution builds directly on the OP's code.

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\fi
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet} % pick a suitable sans-serif text font
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\newcommand\bw{\cellcolor{BurlyWood!80}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\sffamily % optional: switch to sans-serif
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray!40}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\color{blue}\textbf{Répartition semestrielle de mathématiques 2024/2025 -- Lycée Al Amana}} \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{pink!60}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{2\textsuperscript{ème} année Bac. Sciences Math A et B. \quad Premier Semestre}} \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{BurlyWood!30} % hey, why not?
 & & \textbf{Nombres} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Devoirs}} \\
\cline{4-5}
\rowcolor{BurlyWood!30}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Semaine}} &
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Titres de leçons}} & \textbf{d'heurs} & \textbf{Donné} & \textbf{Corrigé} \\ 
\hline
1 & \multirow{3}{*}{Limites et continuité} & \bw 8 & & \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
2 & & \bw 8 & & \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
3 & & \bw 8 & DM1 & \\ 
\hline
4 & \multirow{2}{*}{Suites numériques} & \bw 6 & & DM1 \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
\bw 5 & & \bw 6 & DS1 &  \\ 
\hline
6 & \multirow{2}{*}{Dérivation et étude de fonctions} & \bw 6 & & DS1 \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
7 & & \bw 6 & DM2 &  \\ 
\hline
8 & Primitives & \bw 6 & & DM2 \\ 
\hline
\bw 9 & \multirow{3}{*}{Fonctions logarithmes et exponentielles} & \bw 6 & DS2 & \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
10 & & \bw 8 & & DS2  \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
11 & & \bw 8 & DM3 & \\ 
\hline
\bw 12 & \multirow{4}{*}{Nombres complexes} & \bw 8 & DS3 & DM3 \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
13 & & \bw 4 & & DS3 \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
14 & & \bw 4 & DM4 & \\ 
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
\bw 15 & & \bw 6 & DS4 & DM4 \\ 
\hline
16 & Équations différentielles & \bw 6 & & DS4 \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Total horaire}} & \bw\textbf{98} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{10} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


If you prefer not to write this code yourself, you may find Tables Generator helpful. Here is a simple code snippet created using Tables Generator for your case:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% Beamer presentation requires \usepackage{colortbl} instead of \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{table}[]
  \begin{tabular}{|ccccc|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Répartition semestrielle de mathématiques 2024/2025 - Lycée Al Amana}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Sciences Math A et B. Premier Semestre}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[HTML]{68CBD0} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}}                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}}                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}Devoirs}                                           \\ \cline{4-5} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}semaine}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}Titres de leçons}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{68CBD0}Nombres d’heures}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Donné}                                           & Corrigé                 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                &                         \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                & zz                      \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{Limites et continuité}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{DM1}                                             &                         \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{4}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                &                         \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}5}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{xx}}                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}DS1}                     &                         \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{xx}                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                & DS1                     \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{7}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{xx}                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                &                         \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{8}                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{xx}                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}yy}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{zz}                                              &                         \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[HTML]{FFFE65} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}{\color[HTML]{000000} }}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}{\color[HTML]{000000} }}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}{\color[HTML]{000000} }}            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}{\color[HTML]{000000} }} & {\color[HTML]{000000} } \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Total horaire}                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}98}                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}                                               & 10                      \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The output:


TBH, table generators don't usually make good tables.  For example, the proliferation of \multicolumn{1}{|c|} doesn't make for very readable code.

Please don't suggest these table generators. All these uncalled-for \multicolumn{1}{...}{...} make it very hard to fix problems with the table.
